# ActiveMerchant: Buyer Account Balance Doesn't Decrease

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I'm using ActiveMerchant gem with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1

I already set up a buyer dummy account and a seller dummy account on PayPal using WebPayments Pro. When I run this script and look in my paypal sandbox, my seller account is deposited $10 in funds correctly.

The problem is that when I look at the sandbox for my buyer account, the balance does not decrease. Where is my seller getting the money from?

My code is here:

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_merchant"

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(
  :login => "seller_1328509472_biz_api1.gmail.com",
  :password => "*******",
  :signature => "******"
)

credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
  :type               => "visa",
  :number             => "4193536536887351",
  :verification_value => "123",
  :month              => 2,
  :year               => 2017,
  :first_name         => "TESTING",
  :last_name          => "BUYER"
)

if credit_card.valid?
  response = gateway.authorize(1000, credit_card, :ip => "98.248.144.120", :billing_address => { :name => 'Test User', :company => '', :address1 => '1 Main St', :address2 => '', :city => 'San Jose', :state => 'CA', :zip => '95131'})
  if response.success?
    gateway.capture(1000, response.authorization)
  else
    puts "Response Unsuccessful Error: #{response.message}"
  end
else
  puts "Error: credit card is not valid. #{credit_card.errors.full_messages.join('. ')}"
end
```

Please help me! I have been stuck on this for ages, and I am very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're specifying a credit card directly, there is no 'account' as such that it takes the funds from.
The API method you're using, DoDirectPayment, charges a credit card directly. It is not connected to a PayPal account, nor does it use the balance of a PayPal account.

If you want to charge a PayPal account rather than a credit card, use PayPal Express Checkout: http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout